# What is the name of the Material Design Checkbox in android (android.R.drawable.{checkbox})?

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

As in, this one below:
[image]

I need this default drawable so I can programmatically style it to my auto-generated checkboxes, like so:

```
checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_style);
```

I need this checkbox drawable because Samsung GT-I9300 with Android 4.3 (Jellybean) overrides this style above, like so:

[image]

This is my app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">#88FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#88FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

What is it's name, like `android.R.drawable.(...)`, please?

Comment: You can do using `appCompatCheckbox Widget` of Material Design. Check this http://www.materialdoc.com/check-box/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<style name="Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_check_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:button">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. I hope the moderators won't mind thanking you like this.

Comment: @MonicaLabbao No they'll not. But if you find my answer useful, you can accept this as answer :)

Answer (score 6):

do you want like this for check box

```
checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.abc_btn_check_material);
```

or you can use AppCompatCheckBox like this

```
LinearLayout llParent=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llParent);
AppCompatCheckBox appCompatCheckBox = new AppCompatCheckBox(this);
appCompatCheckBox.setText("agree or not");
llParent.addView(appCompatCheckBox);
```

and add the dependancy for design support lib build.gradle file

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

Comment: It works, but I was warned that the drawable is private, and it doesn't animate. Thank you though! :)

Comment: thanx Monica , use this AppCompactCheckBox , it shows animation also , you can change the background color using colorAccent in color.xml for material color

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use default drawable then no need to set `setButtonDrawable`. just use **App compart(support v7)** its work for Android API 7 to current Android API 23(also animated checkbox).

add this in `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'` in `build.gradle` use **App Compart Theme ** with `colorAccent`

Comment: Samsung GT-I9300 with Android 4.3 (Jellybean) overrides that theme with Jellybean. I'm adding an image to my question.